# get maximum value of a object

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a little problem. I get data from more then one Beacon and I put it into an arrayList. Now I want that the nearest one should be returned.

```
ArrayList<Beacon> arrayList = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
String beaconName;

public void addToBeaconInfo(Beacon beacon) {

    boolean beaconAlreadyInList = false;
    //arrayList.add(beacon);
    beaconName = "" + beacon.getId2() + "" + beacon.getId3();
    //Log.i("BeaconInfo","addBeacon_beaconName: "+beaconName + " distance" + beacon.getDistance());

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        Beacon tempBeacon = arrayList.get(i);

        if(tempBeacon.getId2().equals(beacon.getId2())){
            beaconAlreadyInList = true;
            arrayList.remove(beacon);

            Log.i("BeaconInfo", "addBeacon_tempBeacon: " + beacon.getId3() + " distance: " + beacon.getDistance());
            break;
        }
    }
    if(beaconAlreadyInList == false){
        arrayList.add(beacon);
        Log.i("arrayList","" + beacon.getDistance() + " " + beacon.getBluetoothName());
        double maxDistance = beacon.getDistance();
        //double a = Collections.max(maxDistance);
        //Log.i("maxDistance","" + Math.max());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
Beacon nearest = null;
double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (Beacon beacon: arrayList){
  double maxDistance = beacon.getDistance();
  if (maxDistance < distance) {
    distance = maxDistance;
    nearest = beacon;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your fast request, but this will only work for two beacons.  In my case I have a mutable number of beacons, which I want to sort by his distance.

Comment: you wrote in the question that you need the nearest beacon. if you need to sort just use any of [sort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: thats true, it can be both;) But for more then just two beacons.

Comment: maybe its my fault. I made it now with different arrayLists and Collections. But really thank you for your help;)